# Error in mixedCor(mydat, method = "pearson") : in R

Tags: r, psych

I try perform Point Biserial Correlation. I use `mixedCor` from `library("psych")`

```
library("psych")
mixedCor(mydata,method="pearson")
```

and I got the error

> Error in mixedCor(mydat, method = "pearson") : 
>         I tried to figure out which where continuous and which were polytomous, but failed.  Please try again by specifying x, p, and d.

**data**

```
mydata(dput)=structure(list(x1 = c(9L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 
8L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L), x2 = c(6L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 
6L, 7L), x3 = c(8L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 
11L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 6L, 6L), y = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L)), .Names = c("x1", "x2", "x3", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

x1,x2,x3 is scale var and y is categorical var(0 or 1)

How to perform this type of correlation, that output would be with p-value like this?

```
    y        x3     x2        x1
y   1,0000  ,1114   ,2201   -,2597
    p= ---  p=,631  p=,338  p=,256
x3  ,1114   1,0000  -,2630  ,0457
    p=,631  p= ---  p=,249  p=,844
x2  ,2201   -,2630  1,0000  -,1548
    p=,338  p=,249  p= ---  p=,503
x1  -,2597  ,0457   -,1548  1,0000
    p=,256  p=,844  p=,503  p= ---
```

Comment: Try this: `mixedCor(data=mydata, c=c("x1","x2","x3"), d="y", method="pearson")`

Comment: @MarcoSandri, it works, thank you, can you show how to display p-value and i accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifiy `c` and `d` (the sets of continuous and dichotomous variables, respectively) in `mixedCor`:

```
library(psych)
mixedCor(data=mydata, c=1:3, d=4, method="pearson")

#    x1    x2    x3    y    
# x1  1.00                  
# x2 -0.13  1.00            
# x3  0.03 -0.25  1.00      
# y  -0.32  0.26  0.07  1.00
```

If you need to calculate p-values, you can use the following `mycor.ci` function (a modified version of `cor.ci`):

```
mycor.ci <- function (x, keys = NULL, n.iter = 100, p = 0.05, overlap = FALSE, 
    poly = FALSE, method = "pearson", plot = TRUE, minlength = 5, 
    cvars=NULL, pvars=NULL, dvars=NULL, ...) {
    cl <- match.call()
    n.obs <- dim(x)[1]
    if (is.null(keys) && overlap) 
        overlap <- FALSE
    if (poly) {
        ncat <- 8
        nvar <- dim(x)[2]
        tx <- table(as.matrix(x))
        if (dim(tx)[1] == 2) {
            tet <- tetrachoric(x)
            typ = "tet"
        }
        else {
            tab <- apply(x, 2, function(x) table(x))
            if (is.list(tab)) {
                len <- lapply(tab, function(x) length(x))
            }
            else {
                len <- dim(tab)[1]
            }
            if (is.null(dvars)) dvars <- subset(1:nvar, len == 2)
            if (is.null(pvars)) pvars <- subset(1:nvar, ((len > 2) & (len <= ncat)))
            if (is.null(cvars)) cvars <- subset(1:nvar, (len > ncat))
            if (length(pvars) == ncol(x)) {
                tet <- polychoric(x)
                typ = "poly"
            }
            else {
                plot(pvars)
                tet <- mixedCor(data=x, c=cvars, d=dvars, method="pearson")
                typ = "mixed"
            }
        }
        Rho <- tet$rho

    }
    else {
        Rho <- cor(x, use = "pairwise", method = method)
    }
    if (!is.null(keys)) {
        bad <- FALSE
        if (any(is.na(Rho))) {
            warning(sum(is.na(Rho)), " of the item correlations are NA and thus finding scales that include those items will not work.\n We will try to do it for those  scales which do not include those items.\n         \n Proceed with caution. ")
            bad <- TRUE
            rho <- apply(keys, 2, function(x) colMeans(apply(keys, 
                2, function(x) colMeans(Rho * x, na.rm = TRUE)) * 
                x, na.rm = TRUE))
        }
        else {
            rho <- t(keys) %*% Rho %*% keys
        }
    }
    else {
        rho <- Rho
    }
    if (overlap) {
        key.var <- diag(t(keys) %*% keys)
        var <- diag(rho)
        n.keys <- ncol(keys)
        key.av.r <- (var - key.var)/(key.var * (key.var - 1))
        item.cov <- t(keys) %*% Rho
        raw.cov <- item.cov %*% keys
        adj.cov <- raw.cov
        for (i in 1:(n.keys)) {
            for (j in 1:i) {
                adj.cov[i, j] <- adj.cov[j, i] <- raw.cov[i, 
                  j] - sum(keys[, i] * keys[, j]) + sum(keys[, 
                  i] * keys[, j] * sqrt(key.av.r[i] * key.av.r[j]))
            }
        }
        diag(adj.cov) <- diag(raw.cov)
        rho <- cov2cor(adj.cov)
    }
    rho <- cov2cor(rho)
    nvar <- dim(rho)[2]
    if (n.iter > 1) {
        replicates <- list()
        rep.rots <- list()
        replicates <- parallel::mclapply(1:n.iter, function(XX) {
            xs <- x[sample(n.obs, n.obs, replace = TRUE), ]
            {
                if (poly) {
                  if (typ != "tet") {
                    capture.output(tets <- mixedCor(data=xs, c=cvars, d=dvars, method="pearson"))
                  }
                  else {
                    tets <- tetrachoric(xs)
                  }
                  R <- tets$rho
                }
                else {
                  R <- cor(xs, use = "pairwise", method = method)
                }
                if (!is.null(keys)) {
                  if (bad) {
                    covariances <- apply(keys, 2, function(x) colMeans(apply(keys, 
                      2, function(x) colMeans(R * x, na.rm = TRUE)) * 
                      x, na.rm = TRUE))
                  }
                  else {
                    covariances <- t(keys) %*% R %*% keys
                  }
                  r <- cov2cor(covariances)
                }
                else {
                  r <- R
                }
                if (overlap) {
                  var <- diag(covariances)
                  item.cov <- t(keys) %*% R
                  raw.cov <- item.cov %*% keys
                  adj.cov <- raw.cov
                  key.av.r <- (var - key.var)/(key.var * (key.var - 
                    1))
                  for (i in 1:(n.keys)) {
                    for (j in 1:i) {
                      adj.cov[i, j] <- adj.cov[j, i] <- raw.cov[i, 
                        j] - sum(keys[, i] * keys[, j]) + sum(keys[, 
                        i] * keys[, j] * sqrt(key.av.r[i] * key.av.r[j]))
                    }
                  }
                  diag(adj.cov) <- diag(raw.cov)
                  r <- cov2cor(adj.cov)
                }
                rep.rots <- r[lower.tri(r)]
            }
        })
    }
    replicates <- matrix(unlist(replicates), ncol = nvar * (nvar - 
        1)/2, byrow = TRUE)
    z.rot <- fisherz(replicates)
    means.rot <- colMeans(z.rot, na.rm = TRUE)
    sds.rot <- apply(z.rot, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE)
    sds.rot <- fisherz2r(sds.rot)
    ci.rot.lower <- means.rot + qnorm(p/2) * sds.rot
    ci.rot.upper <- means.rot + qnorm(1 - p/2) * sds.rot
    means.rot <- fisherz2r(means.rot)
    ci.rot.lower <- fisherz2r(ci.rot.lower)
    ci.rot.upper <- fisherz2r(ci.rot.upper)
    low.e <- apply(replicates, 2, quantile, p/2, na.rm = TRUE)
    up.e <- apply(replicates, 2, quantile, 1 - p/2, na.rm = TRUE)
    tci <- abs(means.rot)/sds.rot
    ptci <- pnorm(tci)
    ci.rot <- data.frame(lower = ci.rot.lower, low.e = low.e, 
        upper = ci.rot.upper, up.e = up.e, p = 2 * (1 - ptci))
    cnR <- abbreviate(colnames(rho), minlength = minlength)
    k <- 1
    for (i in 1:(nvar - 1)) {
        for (j in (i + 1):nvar) {
            rownames(ci.rot)[k] <- paste(cnR[i], cnR[j], sep = "-")
            k <- k + 1
        }
    }
    results <- list(rho = rho, means = means.rot, sds = sds.rot, 
        tci = tci, ptci = ptci, ci = ci.rot, Call = cl, replicates = replicates)
    if (plot) {
        cor.plot(rho, numbers = TRUE, cuts = c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05), 
            pval = 2 * (1 - ptci), ...)
    }
    class(results) <- c("psych", "cor.ci")
    return(results)
}
```

The syntax is:

```
library(parallel)
set.seed(123)
mycor.ci(x=mydata, method="pearson", poly=TRUE, cvars=1:3, dvars=4, n.iter=1000)

#  Coefficients and bootstrapped confidence intervals 
#    x1    x2    x3    y    
# x1  1.00                  
# x2 -0.13  1.00            
# x3  0.03 -0.25  1.00      
# y  -0.32  0.26  0.07  1.00

#  scale correlations and bootstrapped confidence intervals 
#       lower.emp lower.norm estimate upper.norm upper.emp    p
# x1-x2     -0.50      -0.51    -0.13       0.29      0.30 0.56
# x1-x3     -0.31      -0.31     0.03       0.40      0.38 0.79
# x1-y      -0.79      -0.75    -0.32       0.24      0.19 0.26
# x2-x3     -0.58      -0.57    -0.25       0.12      0.13 0.19
# x2-y      -0.34      -0.36     0.26       0.72      0.78 0.42
# x3-y      -0.51      -0.48     0.07       0.57      0.56 0.84
```